# Postman not saving new OAuth 2.0 Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

I am trying to set up a new Bearer Token request in **Postman** (v 7.34.0) for the first time in a couple of years and cannot figure out how to get it to save the token to use in a request like it used to.

1. On the Auth tab, I selected OAuth 2.0 type

[image]

2. I click "Get New Access Token" button, and it opens the dialog, which I filled out with the Access Token URL, username, and password.

[image]

3. When I click "Request Token", the token request is **successful**, but the dialog stays open and no other dialogs appear.
4. If I cancel the dialog and open the **Postman console**, I can see the new Access Token that just came back.

[image]

5. When I go back to the Auth tab, the new Access token does not appear in the list. [image]

6. If I **manually** copy that new bearer token from the console and **manually** paste it into the Bearer Token type or **manually** create an Authorization header, it does work. But that token value is never saved in the Access Token list and is never selectable again. I can only reuse by pasting it in everywhere I need to use that token. So every couple of hours when it expires, I have to go back in, request a new token, and then manually paste it in again in every request I need to use it.

Now granted, I'm not a Postman expert, and it's been a few years since I've set up an OAuth 2.0 bearer token in Postman, but I remember that Postman used to save these tokens to an Access Token list, and if you wanted to request a new one, you just hit the button, and it would automatically use the new one in every request (it would automatically appear in the request header).

Something changed in Postman in the past year or so, and now this is a lot more work. Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I am signed into Postman with the same account I've been using for more than 3 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting a window that says Manage Access Tokens
[image: manage access tokens]

Clicking Use Token will populate it into the token field.
[image: access token filled in]

Comment: Yes, that's the screen I remember. But I can't seem to get it to come up. My suspicion is this api's token service response is not OAuth 2.0-compliant and is returning a proprietary json object, which Postman doesn't recognize.

Comment: If the token response is supposed to look like the one here, it doesn't.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization-code-request-response.html

Comment: You were correct. The API token service was returning a custom token response that was not OAuth 2.0-compliant, so I had to add a script to Postman to parse it out and store it in an Environment variable.